# How to select elements for Frank using UIQuery/UISpec?

Tags: ios, testing, cucumber

I've been using Frank automation tool to write tests for iOS using cucumber. If I understand correctly, I can point to the different UI elements using UIQuery selectors. I've had a hard time finding documentation about these selectors. How exactly do they work?

Particularly, right now I'm trying to select a `UITextField` which the Symbiote Frank inspector identifies as `UITextField with label "UserName"`. I've explicitly set that identifier with Xcode using the *Accessibility Label* property. I've seen that by default, Frank uses the *placeholder* property to refer to the `UITextField`s but I don't want to use that.

Comment: I too faced similar issues with Frank. There is little documentation on how the UIQuery selectors work and all I could do was use the Frank inspector to identify fields. I believe it's similar to Apple's UIAutomation in that if you want to use different names you must manually specify them via the accessibility label property. Sorry this doesn't answer anything further than what you've mentioned already.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial response to the particular problem I had regarding how to refer to items by the *accessibility label* property. For a `UITextField` with the *accessibility label* set to `UserName` the selector `"view marked: 'UserName'"` seems to work.

The more general question about how selectors work is still open.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Igor Query Language: https://github.com/dhemery/igor/wiki

I modeled Igor after CSS selectors, and added some syntax to handle some situations that CSS doesn't handle (e.g. "cousins" and selecting views based on the characteristics of their descendants).

The Igor syntax for your query would be:

> `UITextField[accessibilityLabel=='UserName']`

The grammar for Igor is described completely on the wiki.  The wiki also has some examples, though probably not enough.